# W3C Validate UserControl which contains CSS

Tags: asp.net, css

I have written a .net usercontrol for a gallery which works quite well in my web application if there is a gallery on my page. The problem is when I go to validate my page, using XHTML 1.0 Strict, I get the document type does not allow element "link" here.

I've done a bit of research and it is because I have a stylesheet embedded within the usercontrol, and is called from the body of the masterpage, so it doesn't validate. I can move the stylesheet out of the usercontrol and into the masterfile, but I don't necessary want the stylesheet loading up on every single page. What is the best way to do this - I was hoping to contain the stylesheet within the  usercontrol so its simple to 'manage'.

Any advice would be great. Also thinking, do I need to remove the javascript out of the usercontrol as well?

This is the user control in question

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Debug="true" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Gallery.ascx.cs" Inherits="Gallery" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
Namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<link ID="FancyboxCSS" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="" runat="server" />
<link ID="FancyboxButtonsCSS" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="" runat="server" />

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        maxWidth: 800,
        maxHeight: 800,
        fitToView: true,
        aspectRatio: true,
        openEffect: 'fade',
        closeEffect: 'fade',
        nextEffect: 'fade',
        prevEffect: 'fade',

        helpers: {
            title: {
                type: 'outside'
            },
            overlay: {
                opacity: 0.8,
                css: {
                    'background-color': '#000'
                }
            },
            buttons: {}
        }
    });
});
```

```
<div id="gallery" runat="server">
//images here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here for anyone else looking for the same thing in the future http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmllink(v=vs.80).aspx

```
// Define an HtmlLink control.
HtmlLink myHtmlLink = new HtmlLink();
myHtmlLink.Href = "~/StyleSheet.css";
myHtmlLink.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
myHtmlLink.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");

// Add the HtmlLink to the Head section of the page.
Page.Header.Controls.Add(myHtmlLink);
```

Answer (score 0):

A markup validator processes documents in a markup language, such as HTML or XML, and a document must be complete. For example, an HTML document must minimally contain a `title` element. And things like `<%@` should not be included: they are not part of the HTML document but instructions to software that generates HTML.

So you need to submit a complete, generated HTML document, if you wish to validate.

Comment: Hi Jukka, thanks for reply, I will edit my question with the html code the masterpage is producing, I just included the usercontrol as I thought it might help.